# while debugging using GDB No output after calling a user defined function in C

Tags: gdb

While debugging using gdb, I am calling the `nc_print` function as
`(gdb)call nc_print()` but there is no output and no warning.

```
void nc_print()
{
     printf("ramanuj\n");
}
```

I am finding that gdb fails to call the `nc_print`. I am not getting why is it happening. May i know the possible reason.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, can you post whole gdb session from very beginning ?

Comment: atleast you can say in which situation gdb fails to call the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am finding that gdb fails to call the nc_print.

Your conclusion that GDB did not call `nc_print` is likely wrong. If you add a call to `abort()` to `nc_print`, does your program abort? If so, your conclusion *is* wrong.

> I am not getting why is it happening

What is *most likely* happening is that your inferior (being debugged) program has its `stdout` redirected to a file (or a pipe), and thus *fully buffered*.

Things will likely work as you expect them if you add `fflush(stdout)`, or use `fprintf(stderr, "ramanuj\n")`.

Comment: Many Thanks It works. Is there any way to increase the buffer size while debugging.